# Print File Paths and Filenames within a Directory into a CSV

Tags: awk, sed, find

I have a directory that contains several files.  For instance:

> File1.bam
>   File2.bam
>   File3.bam

I want to create a .csv file that contains 2 columns and includes a header:

> Name,Path
>   File1, /Path/To/File1.bam
>   File2, /Path/To/File2.bam
>   File3, /Path/To/File3.bam

I've managed to piece together a way of doing this in separate steps, but it involves creating a csv with the path, appending with the filename, and then appending again with the header.  I would like to add both the filename and path in 1 step, so that there is no possibility of linking an incorrect filename and path.

In case it matters, I'm trying to do this within a script that is running in a batch job (SLURM), and the output CSV will be used in subsequent workflow steps.

```
find ~/Desktop/test -iname '*.csv' -type f >bamlist1.csv
awk '{print FILENAME (NF?",":"") $0}' *.csv > test.csv
{ echo 'Name, Path'; cat bamlist.csv; } > bamdata.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested but should be close:

```
find ~/Desktop/test -name '*.bam' -type f |
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS=","; print "Name", "Path" }
    { fname=$0; sub(".*/","",fname); print fname, $0 }
' > bamdata.csv
```

Like your original script the above assumes that none of your file/directory names contain newlines or commas.

If you have GNU find you can just do:

```
{ echo "Name,Path"; find ~/Desktop/test -name '*.bam' -type f -printf '%f,%p\n' } > bamdata.csv
```

Comment: The first script generates bamdata.csv, but it only contains: Name, Path

Comment: Then the `find` command isn't producing any output. test/fix that.

Comment: Thank you.  I just needed to change "-name" to "-name" and it is now working perfectly.

Comment: One more question: I'm trying to remove the ".bam" extension from text in the Name column.  I tried adjusting the regex expression to within sub to the following sub(".*/(.*)?\.bam$", "", fname).  The regex expression works fine when used on a tester site, but within the script it ends up printing nothing in the Name column.  Any ideas?

Comment: regexp test sites prove that a given regexp works on that test site, they don't prove anything about how that regexp will work in any other tool. They're practically useless. Just add a `; sub(/\.bam$/,"",fname)` after the existing sub().